# Google Maps API V3 Quota and Key Usage

Tags: javascript, google-maps

First, our api key is not utilized in the url that calls the Google maps API. I know it's not required, but I am wondering if that 25,000 api calls applies to us if we don't use our key. 
Secondly, does that 25,000 api call quota apply to our Web application or each individual user? 
I added a key to the url that makes the api call and it does up the quota limit everytime a session is started. Obviously the number doesn't go up when I do not include our key. 
I have been searching for a  clear response on this and have not found oneBTW I am using the client side api.

Comment: If I recall right no key means they'll use the IP address to limit.  The benefit of using the key is they know how to contact you if you are going over and being denied service.  Been a while since I looked into it though, and it could have changed too.

Comment: this is where I am confused. Will it use the user's IP address or will it use my servers IP address.

Answer (score 0):

Looks to be here:
https://developers.google.com/maps/usagelimits/

So if you use the embed API there are no limits.  Otherwise it limits to 25,000 per day, based on the api key if provided, or the site if not.  I am guessing "site" means "domain" but I didn't see it specified anywhere.